# Easy Rails Issue: Global User Variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, global-variables

I have a bunch of different controllers, and I want to be able to do the standard "Welcome, User."  How do I assign the user variable to make it possible to access from any controller?

Here's what I have so far in the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :authorize

  protect_from_forgery

    private

        def current_user
            User.find(session[:user_id])
        end

  protected

    def authorize
        unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
            redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Please Login"
        end
    end
end
```

Here's my application.html.haml file:

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        %title Pears
        = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
        = javascript_include_tag "application"
        = csrf_meta_tags
    %body
        %header
            = link_to('Home', '/')
            - if session[:user_id]
                Welcome, 
                = current_user.firstname
                = link_to('Logout', logout_path, method: :delete)
            - else
                = link_to('Login', login_path)
                = link_to('Signup', signup_path)
        = yield
```

What's the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to be able to embed the username into a welcome message, I would probably just store it in the session (as an optimization, to keep from fetching it every time), and then create a partial that displays

```
Hello, <%= session[:username] %>
```

and include the partial in your layout, or wherever you want to display this message.

If you're looking for more than a username or small amounts of data like that, a partial is still your best bet to display it, but to fetch the information from the database a before_filter to load the data (as suggested by MrYoshiji), is probably a good idea.

Comment: Hey thanks!  I think this is what I needed.  For those who have the same question, I just added a new declaration in my sessions_controller "create" method, `session[:firstname] = user.first_name`.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is a private method, do it public, and your code probably will be working.

Comment: But it's in application_controller, shouldn't even private work?  If not, what is it private to?

Comment: private method belongs only to ApplicationController, but you run method from view.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, views can't call controller methods. However you can allow this for specific methods if you so desire, for example

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def current_user
    ...
  end
  helper_method :user
end
```

Whether the user is fetched from the database each time or has some data stored in the session doesn't really matter, but your view shouldn't be coupled to that detail.

I would also be slightly wary of stashing just the user name in the session as an optimisation without first understanding how much of a performance difference it makes

Comment: What makes you wary about that?  It seems like any session data would be more efficient than querying the database every pageload.

Comment: Also, -- just googled helper_method, and it gives a solution to the exact problem.  http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Comment: What makes me wary is premature optimisation.